# This jQuery block creates a strange loop by some error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Curious if anything jumps out here.

But when I run this code block :

```
    $items = $('ul#jobs_to_approve').find('.checked').parents('li');
    $items.fadeOut(function(){
      $items.find('.checked').removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');
      $.each($items, function(i, val) { 
        $.post($(val).attr('data-url'), function(data) {
          $(val).attr('data-url', $(val).attr('data-url').replace('approve','disapprove') );
        });
      });
      SSK.quickbooks.check_active_approvals();
      $('ul#jobs_to_sync').prepend($items.fadeIn());
    });
  },
```

So if I have 2 items selected for $items, by the time it gets to the end, it is sending 4 Ajax requests. For 3 items, it sends 9 ajax requests. For 4, it sends 16 AJAX requests. There's a pattern. ;)

My question is..why is it not sticking to the original number?

Comment: Sorry, not it's on my local.. I just tried to add a class to its instantiation, and then remove it at the finish, and it still sends the Square of items selected.

Comment: it iws wierd behaviour. Can you post it on jsfiddle?

Comment: your code is weird. Why on earth are you using `.parents()` just to call `.find(".checked")` two lines later. This makes no sense. I know, you want to fadeOut the parent, but your selectors are really costly performance-wise.

Comment: @Christoph, I need to select only LI's that have been checked.

Comment: I know. But this would be more effective: `$items = $('ul#jobs_to_approve').find('.checked'); $items.parents("li").fadeOut(function(){$items.removeClass() ... $items.attr("data-url"... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The docs for `.fadeOut` say:](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

> If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

You're iterating all elements each time the callback is fired for one element. So for `n` elements, you're making `n * n` requests. You don't need to loop inside the callback (`$.each`) because the callback *itself* basically acts as a loop.

You probably want to run the other code in the callback only once, too.